# Fork docker repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I want to keep the images that I used in my docker hub account while maintaining reference to the pulled image. Something like when you fork a project in github.

Currently I have tried [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) image. Now that I am satisfied with it, I committed the working container to username/nginx-proxy image and push it.

The problem with this approach is it is like a fresh image and it doesn't show the layer from jwilder/nginx-proxy. No documentation or even Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you push the image, there is no reference to the original, that behavior is normal. You can put that reference or link using your "repo info".

The Dockerfile is only shown if you did an automated build linking your github or bitbucket account and the push is automatically done based on the Dockerfile of your project.